# will the magenet become weightless when made float on super conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism

will the magnet actually become weightless when floated on superconductor "on specific temprature--ie: in super conductive mode" or it actually has its weight  but only seem to be floating due to the super conductive effect ?

Comment: That would imply that you're removing its gravitational effect, but that would be wrong.  Superconductors aren't anti-gravity devices anymore than magnets are anti-gravity devices.

Answer (score 1):

Weightlessness means there is not gravitational pull on that object or the gravitational force acting on an object(pulling it downwards) is counterbalanced by some force acting upwards.

In "Superconductive mode" there are magnetic field lines that causes repulsion on the magnet and hence making it float in air(literally weightless).

For more understanding read this question: [How do superconducting materials float in magnetic field?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/48421/how-do-superconducting-materials-float-in-magnetic-field)